# API Management Service can't find API definition

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm trying to create a new API Management Service (AMS) on Azure. I'm facing an issue I have never had before. I have my OpenAPI file in a public URL. If I paste this URL to create a new APIs in AMS, I always receive an error

> Unable to download specified file. Please ensure the URL is valid and the file is publicly accessible.

[image]

Then, I tried to download this OpenAPI definition from the Azure Console and it can reach the file and download it. This issue happens from yesterday before I could use the same OpenAPI file without problem.

Also, I checked the configuration of the Virtual Machine where the APIs are hosted. It seems correct and I can reach the file from a browser.

Comment: I assume the error you met comes from the url. When I call `http://51.137.177.245:8000/openapi.json`, I got the json response but not started to download so that it said `unable to download ...`. By the way, I copied the response and save it as a json file locally, but when I uploaded the file, I met the error of `unable to parse specified file`, then I checked and found that you missed servers.url. After adding a value, it could be uploaded successfully.https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ0v4.png   https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPJrO.png

Comment: Here's a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions) describes restrictions on api import. It refers users to go to azure apim to choose an existing api to see the format for openapi. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQsKq.png

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. I missed the server url parameter. I don't know the `unable to download...` error. What kind of configuration is required to avoid that?

Comment: Maybe related to the ip address. Can you use a domain instead? I upload my json file into azure storage blob. And I can use the file url into apim. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwmuu.png

Comment: I'm working on the server URL... I'm a .NET developer and I must cope with `R` API, not really my cup of tea.

Comment: It seems that you need to upload file saved locally. Can you upload file from local place?

Comment: If you feel my suggestions helpful to you, could you accept it as the answer? Thank for your response :)

Comment: How do you receive the message `Unable to download...`? What tool do you use?

Comment: I use the same url as yours. Put `http://51.137.177.245:8000/openapi.json` into field OpenAPIspecification, then got the error `Unable to down specified file. Please ensure the url is valid ...`, Didn't use any tools here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long call with Microsoft support, I found the issue. In the **Network Security Groups**, I added a new **Inbound Security Rule**.

First, Source. I saw there is an option for **Service Tag**. If I select Service Tag, the following dropdown change the label in **Source service tag**. From this dropdown, you there is an option for **ApiManagement**.

Wrong choice. You have to allow select **IP** from the dropdown list and type the IP of the API Management Service.

I have create a [post on my blog](https://www.puresourcecode.com/tools/azure-tools/how-to-use-an-azure-api-management-service/) to explain step by step what you have to do. Hopefully, it could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The error of `unable to download ...` perhaps comes from the ip address url, because when I fill the field with an azure storage blob url, I received no error.

[image]

And I saved your request response into a json file locally and upload it to apim, I got the error of `unable to parse specified file`, I found it resulted from missing `servers.url`.

I think you can try to add api instance by uploading json file from localhost.